# Character NULL (ASCII 0) not processed from Javascript on Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, utf-8, character-encoding, internet-explorer-9

Function **d(a)** displays an alert with the ASCII value of each character from string **a**. One of the characters is ASCII 0, that I have displayed it on this post with [NULL].
This is the output I receive on different browsers:

**GOOGLE CHROME - CORRECT**
- String length: 3
- Alert outputs: 116, 0, 114

**INTERNET EXPLORER 9 - INCORRECT**
- String length: 2
- Alert outputs: 116, 114

What can I do to have these characters displayed in Internet Explorer 9? THANKS

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="x-user-defined">
function d(a)
{
  a=(a+"").split("");
  var l=a.length;
  alert(l); // Displays string length
  for(var z=0;z<l;z++)alert(a[z].charCodeAt(0));
};
d("t[NULL]r");
</script>
```

Comment: Try `String.fromCharCode(116, 0, 114).length`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't put non-printable characters directly into code - it most likely will not work. Instead, use the correct entity `\0`.

Comment: Well it's not `\0` it's `\u0000` but yes.

Comment: Erm, `\0`, `\x00` and `\u0000` are synonymous. Just like `\n`, `\x0A` and `\u000A`.

Comment: Wow I cannot believe that I've been as apparently confused as I've been; thanks for that ... dang I need to check my brain or something.

Comment: Thanks! But then why it works in Google Chrome. Perhaps is this a x-user-defined charset issue?

Comment: I have never heard of `x-user-defined` character set. Chrome is probably set up to treat your script as binary data rather than text, or something.